# Nested GraphQL servers / microservices

Tags: microservices, graphql, apollo-server

I would like to replace all my REST APIs with GraphQL (apollo-server preferred). It's clear to me how to use GraphQL in monolithic apps but it's not clear how to do it for microservices.

The main API server consists of multiple microservices where each microservice exposes its own REST API through which the central API server communicates with it. I would like to replace all these REST APIs with GraphQL thus I would get microservices as nested GraphQL servers communicating with each other through GraphQL instead of REST.

The problem that I'm facing is how to easily build a GraphQL query string for microservices based on the received attributes in the resolver of the main GraphQL server. There is no way to tell GraphQL to return all the fields for microservice. The best way would be to simple forward just a part of a the main query further to a microservice.

Any ideas? Do you think that REST is still more appropriate for microservices then GraphQL?

Comment: I'd like to know if graphql servers can be nested as well.  It seems to me that the super-graphql server should be able to get the schemas from the sub-graphql servers and offer an aggregated schema.  Is this what you are interested in?

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to use [WAMP protocol](http://crossbar.io) and then build a network of all of your functionality.
Finally serve it under 1 GraphQL server

Comment: Your link is broken